# Javascript using mailto: with Mac and Windows

Tags: javascript, email

I try to create a new email on the default email client independent of the browser and OS.

For this I use the standard

```
window.location.href="mailto:a@b.de;b@c.de;c@d.de?subject=sub&body=body";
```

command.

The problem is, that I need to set multiple receipients.
With outlook the multiple addresses must be seperated by a ";" while in apple mail you need to seperate them by ","

So how can I handle this? Is there any way to detect the email clients name or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Regards

Claus

Comment: Thanks for this link but it will not fit my needs for 100% because not every mac user is using apple mail. So detecting the client instead of the OS would be much more precise.

Comment: You just can't detect the mail client from the browser.

Comment: And what about users who use web-based mail clients?  Or other native mail clients?  Mobile users?  Etc.?  This is precisely why sending a message from server-side code is preferred over using `mailto:` links.  A `mailto:` link is convenient, and can conform to limited standards (semi-colons in this case), but you have zero control over what the client does with that link.